# Highlight selected item on a gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, selector

I am trying to highlight a selected item on a gridview (dinamically populated with an adapter), but it is not working.

I did research and i even tried to copy exactly the selector of other people and even the way that they put it on the gridview but i am not being able to put it working.

It just doesn't do anything. The background of each item is white (like i wanted), but when i press it (it it is on top of a textview or a imageview (part of the gridview item) it doesn't do anything. If i press out of the imageView or textview, it will do what i want.

EDIT : I have listeners for the images and the textviews, so it might be interfering with this selector ? How could i solve this problem?

Here is the code of the activity where i create the gridview :

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highway_appselection_activity);
    gridView= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.HighwayGridView);

    gridView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
```

Here is the xml of each item of this gridview : (where i define the background as the selector)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/HighwayGridViewItem"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/highway_appselection_selector"
android:padding="5dp">

<cm.aptoide.lite.HighwayCustomImageView
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:id="@+id/highwayGridViewItemIcon"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<!-- does this need to be my custom image view anymore? CHeck on that-->
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/highwayGridViewItemName"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:text="texto de teste"
       android:textSize="10sp"
        android:focusable="true"
       android:ellipsize="marquee"
       android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
       android:layout_weight="2"
       android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:id="@+id/highwayGridViewItemInfoButton"/>
```

And here is my selector :

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green_main_color" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/green_main_color" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/green_main_color" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
```

I might be missing something, I am new to Android, sorry if there is any rookie mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create file `selector.xml` as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/green_main_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/green_main_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>

</selector>
```

Put your selector file in drawable folder as `drawable/selector.xml` and then in your gridView:

```
 <GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" 
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Comment: But i already have that. My highway_appselection_selector is already on the drawable folder and i am already putting the line 

android:background="@drawable/highway_appselection_selector"  on my gridview

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Ok please try to update your selctor.xml as above and give it a try.

Comment: Hey @AndroidGeek i tried it, but nothing highlights with that code. With the one i have, it highlights when i click outside of the imageview or the textview, but not when i click on top of them.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves try `listSelector` instead of background.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves plz note you must have your gridview in `RelativeLayout` for listSelector attribute to work.

Comment: Hey @AndroidGeek i managed to solve it. I had to put the background on the linearlayout of my item and removed the listeners of the imageview and textview from inside of it (since they are not really that usefull and i managed to find another solution for them). Thank you for your help !

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves pleasure :)

Comment: Hey @AndroidGeek i have another problem related with this, since now i want to leave the background painted. Do you have any idea on how to do that ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224237/trying-to-highlight-a-selected-item-from-a-gridview

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves ok i am replying over there.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Thanks for accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

try this :

```
          int nPrevSelGridItem = -1;
      gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                View viewPrev;

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    try {
                        if (nPrevSelGridItem != -1) {
                            viewPrev = (View) gridview.getChildAt(nPrevSelGridItem);
                            viewPrev.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                        nPrevSelGridItem = position;
                        if (nPrevSelGridItem == position) {
                            //View viewPrev = (View) gridview.getChildAt(nPrevSelGridItem);
                            view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Try above solution@Filipe Gonçalves

Comment: That is not working because i have in order for it to access to the nPrevSelGridItem, it has to be final, and then if it is final you can't do the 
                        nPrevSelGridItem = position

Comment: this solution perfectly Worked for me thats why i suggest this one for you@FilipeGonçalves

Comment: Hey Anantham thank you for your help. I managed to solve it by removing the listeners from the imageview and the textview that i had, and put the selector on the linear layout that contains them. Thank you for your help !