# Trying to highlight a selected item from a GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I have a Gridview and when i press a certain element, i want paint the background.

I have an adapter to load the gridview elements dinamically. And i have a listener on that adapter.
On that listener, i put the background with the color that i want, but then it also paints another element down the list (i guess the one with the same position, after the view is reloaded).

Important : My minimum API is 9, and i can't really change it.

Here is the code for my getView method (from the adapter) :

```
   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.highwayappselectionitem,parent, false);

        viewHolder.appImageIcon=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.highwayGridViewItemIcon);
        viewHolder.appNameLabel=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.highwayGridViewItemName);
        viewHolder.appInfoButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.highwayGridViewItemInfoButton);
        viewHolder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.HighwayGridViewItem);

    }else{
        view= convertView;
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    viewHolder.appNameLabel.setText(appsList.get(position).getAppName());
    viewHolder.appImageIcon.setImageDrawable(appsList.get(position).getImageIcon());


    view.setTag(viewHolder);

    viewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(position,0));

    return view;
}
```

and here is the listener for the linearlayout (that represents each item):

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        if(selectedView==0 || selectedView==1){

            appName=appsList.get(position).getAppName();
            filePath=appsList.get(position).getFilePath();
            appLogo=appsList.get(position).getImageIcon();

           v.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_grey));           

            System.out.println("Just pressed the app ... "+appName);
            System.out.println("His filePath is ... "+filePath);

            HighwayGridViewAppItem tmpSelectedItem= new HighwayGridViewAppItem(appLogo, appName, filePath);
            selectedAppsList.add(tmpSelectedItem);

            System.out.println("AppSelectionCUstomAdapter : Added a new application to the list of selected apps .!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!.........");
            System.out.println("AppselectioncustomAdaptaer  :   The size of the selectedAppsList is now  : "+selectedAppsList.size());

        }else{
            //pressed the info button
            System.out.println("This will be implemented later, need access to the webservices");
        }
    }
}
```

ignore the if(selected view ==0 or ==1 it is not being used anymore, i can delete it... ).

Also, appsLIst is a list my custom class of items. There i have a boolean attribute to represent if it is selected or not.

WHat is happening is , imagine this gridview:

A B C

D E F

---

G H I

J K L

The grey line represents the scroll... if scroll those new elements show up.
If i press B, it selects B, but it also selects H.

I tried to do research but the problems that I found weren't the same.

Something that might help.. the gridview used to add repeated elemetns, so when i add the elements to the gridview i check if the list of elements already has a similar element, if so i dont add it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line when you want to keep selected some item of gridview after selection.

```
((BaseAdapter) gridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Edit** I think there is problem in getView method that's why you are getting duplicate values:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View view = convertView;
    if (view== null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.highwayappselectionitem, parent, false);
    }
```

}

Comment: But the problem is that i am doing to the changes in the listener, that is inside the adapter class (it is a nested class), so i don't have access to the gridview inside there

Comment: then simply use `notifyDataSetChanged();` after making changes.

Comment: Yes, i already put the notifiyDataSetChanged(); but another (main) problem is that it is painting some icons that it shouldn't.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Ok but i didn't see anywhere in your code. Try inside onclick method.

Comment: it already paints. The problem is that i is also painting items that shouldn't be painted (that situation  that explained at the end, of B and H items being painted after i pressed B.

Comment: But i already had that code, it is not working. But i agree, the problem must be something related with the recycling

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Ok give it a last try, after than i will do your complete code.

Comment: That is the full thing, then i just have some getters this adapter class. Then i just have an activity where i get the gridview from the layout and where i set an adapter ( an instance of this one) to that gridview.

Comment: I solved this issue, Basically what was happening was that i was setting the background of the view well, but since it is being reused (because i am using a viewholder for effiency), and since that view had already the background on that color, when it was going to be reused, it would be reused WITH that background color. The solution was simply to write an else statement and put the background back to the 1st color.

Thank you for your help !