# How to colorize only one row in gridview on event click?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Follow code:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    List<string> numbers = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        numbers.Add((i + 1).ToString());
    }

    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.grid_1);

    gridView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;

    //Here event click item
    gridView.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
    { 
        gridView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#FFC107"));
    };

    ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Resource.Layout.item_1, numbers);

    gridView.Adapter = adapter;

    return view;
}
```

When I click on 1 item, it's painting the entire gridview. How to paint only where it was clicked ?

Follow picture:

[image]

When you click on number 5, this happens:

[image]

I want you to only paint in 5. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `GridView` item click, the `AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs` includes the `View` that was touched:

```
gridView.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
{ 
   e.View.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
};
```

Comment: Works well, can not duplicate selected colors. How do I run a single selection?

Comment: Code `gridView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;` not work.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Save the prior View that selected in a variable and upon receiving a new item click, if there is one saved set the prior View color back to some default, set the new View to your selection color and save that new View as your prior View.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda If you are trying to use `ChoiceMode`, that is based off of a "Selection", review the question/answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204682/highlight-selected-item-on-a-gridview

Comment: Hi Sushi, How can I leave the default background in the first position? Please see the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237848/how-to-set-background-in-the-first-position-as-default