# How to set background in the first position as default?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Follow code:

**Fragment1.cs:**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.grid_view);

    gridView.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (view_1 != null)
        {
            view_1.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
        }
        view_1 = e.View;
        e.View.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#FFC107"));
    };

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Resource.Layout.item_1, numbers);

    gridView.Adapter = adapter;

    return view;
}
```

**item_1.axml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

**fragment_1.axml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:columnWidth="40dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="15dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Example picture:

[image]

I want to paint yellow in the first position.

I want to make the background in the first position in `OnCreateView`, is it possible?

I have a gridview with numbers I need to load a background in the first position which is the number 1. How can I do this?

Comment: You must select the item to which you want to apply the color in the OnCreate event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Like `ListView`, `GridView` also reuses its children. So if use `View.GetChildAt(position)` and set the background color. you will get multiple views rendered with background color.

So, if you only want the first child to be rendered with background color, you have to rewrite the Adapter to `SetBackgroundColor` when `position==0` and clear the color if `position!=0`:

The `GetView` method of your custom adapter:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view=null;
    if (convertView != null)
    {
        view = convertView;
    }
    else
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.FromContext(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.item1,null);
    }

    if (position == 0)
    {
        view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
    }
    else
    {
        view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
    }

    (view as TextView).Text = _items[position];
    return view;
}
```

Update:

Here is the complete codes of Adapter:

```
public class MyGridViewAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    string[] _items;
    public MyGridViewAdapter(string[] items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }
    public override int Count => _items.Length;

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return _items[position];
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view=null;
        if (convertView != null)
        {
            view = convertView;
        }
        else
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.FromContext(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.item1,null);
        }

        if (position == 0)
        {
            view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
        }
        else
        {
            view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
        }

        (view as TextView).Text = _items[position];
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get error: `"Fragment1.GetView (int, View, ViewGroup)": no suitable method found for override`

Comment: Do I need to use `override`?

Comment: See the documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.IAdapter.GetView/

Comment: Yes, you need to override this method, if you need sample codes for a custom Adapter, please refer to [Referencing a Custom Row View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/customizing-appearance#referencing-a-custom-row-view)

Comment: What is `_items[position];` ?  I do not see `_items` in your code.

Comment: I've added the complete codes of my adapter. Please check my update. Also, you can refer to [the complete demo](https://github.com/elvisxia/TextAppearenceDemo).

Answer (score 0):

You must select the item to which you want to apply the color in the OnCreate event

```
int itemposition = 0;
View tv = gridView.GetChildAt(itemposition);
tv.SetBackgroundColor(Color.ParseColor("#FFC107"));
```

Comment: I get error: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Variable `tv` returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Since GridView doesn't get populated from the adapter after the first layout pass, you have to change the background color using a [`ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.ViewTreeObserver/). To get your `View`'s `ViewTreeObserver`, you can use the [`View.ViewTreeObserver`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Views.View.ViewTreeObserver/) property. Add a `ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener` to the `ViewTreeObserver` by using it's [`AddOnGlobalLayoutListener()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnGlobalLayoutListener/p/Android.Views.ViewTreeObserver+IOnGlobalLayoutListener/) method. Your GridView should be populated by the first time the listener gets invoked.

Get the cell's view by using `GridView`'s [`GetChildAt(int position)`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.ViewGroup.GetChildAt/p/System.Int32/) method in the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` and set the background color just like you did in your code sample.